# Are hyphens needed in a noun-phrase that precedes 'manner'?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, adverbs

I sometimes use "manner" to use noun-phrases as adverbs, like "in the manner of a vigilant watchdog". If I reverse the order, does the noun phrase then have to be hypenated? Like so: "in a vigilant-watchdog manner"

Comment: jimmy joyce, in cases like yours the best is to use two hyphens 'in a vigilant-watchdog-manner', though.

Comment: There comes a time when stylistic considerations are at least as important as acceptable grammar. I'd almost certainly use 'like a vigilant watchdog'.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: That is not the normal way to do it according to style books, which would be *in a vigilant-watchdog manner*, as Jimmy says. Either way, I agree with Edwin that compound adjectives are overused and often ugly, so I wouldn't write that either. Brevity rules!

Comment: Thanks guys! Btw I disagree with the 'duplicate' mark -- the other q discusses compound words, such as "master-at-arms". But such words are _always_ hyphenated. My question addresses noun phrases, which are usually _not_ hyphenated. If the claim is that in my example, "vigilant watchdog" becomes a compound word or phrasal adjective when preceding "manner", that's fine, but doesn't seem to be a duplication, strictly speaking. And yes, I try to avoid this pattern too. I was, um, asking for a friend...

Comment: @regdwigt please see above comment. I should have used @ above, sorry.